# Cypress unable to select elements in modal

Tags: angular, cypress

Cypress cannot seem to interact with the elements in my modal for some reason (cant click on my elements). The UI gives me a hint why this might be happening

[image]

this is what I see when I use `cy.get('.modal-button')`.

[image]

`cy.get('.modal-button').contains('No Template').click()` looks like. But the click does not actually happen. Cypress does not give me any error message, and just goes on.

some more context:
we are using ng-bootstrap for the modal. There is a 0.5 second animation while showing the modal but all actions described happens after a cy.wait of 3 seconds. I tried using `{force: true}` in the click, and tried other selectors/contains  but that doesn't help either.

It just fails silently:
[image] just moving on as if the click happened. ( these are two approaches I tried, My actual class names are different than what I used for illustration here )

Comment: the default timeout for get is 4000 milliseconds, unless you are overiding it. so the extra 3 second wait, would be in addition to that. based on your screenshot the `No Template` appears to be nested after you have first selected an option in the left hand column. areyou first choosing an option in the left hand column before trying to get the `no Template` button?. Also, what is the error that cyppres throws? that it can't find the element, or that the element is in the shadow dom ....?

Comment: There is a `.active-midrow-button` class that applies to the option highlighted in blue `no template` in this case. I tried that first and the same thing happens.

It fails silently with no error. I added a screenshot to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `.then()`

```
   cy.get(".modal-button").then((el) => {
      if (el.text() == "No Template") {
        el.click({ force: true }); //el.trigger('click')
      }
    });
```

The issue might also be with the locator you are using.